How to add @available(*,deprecated) attribute to my struct
I have created a macro like below
@MyMacro(true)
struct X {

}

should expand like
@available(*,deprecated)
struct X {
    
}

Here i am passsing a boolean flag, according to that flag @available attribute should show/hide.How can i implement this functionality by uisng AttachedMacro.

Macros can only add attributes to members of the attached declaration, so no this is not possible.
